# Javascript: Can Math.PI survive a calculation?

Tags: javascript, pi

Let's say I want to calculate with Pi and the result would "contain" Pi as well if I do the calculation *on the paper*.

Is there any way I can tell Javascript to calculate with Pi and maintain it?

From my recent view, this is not possible as computer systems are limited. I assume you need something like "symbolic calculation" plus a parser. But maybe I am wrong and there is another way.

I also thought of setting PI after calculation using `value/Math.PI` and in case this is very close to an integer, output "pi" instead. But well, this is no clean solution.

For clarification: Instead of a digit I want to output Pi. And it should be ensured that it is really Pi (by calculation).

Comment: I honestly don't understand the question.

Comment: Instead of a digit I want to output Pi. And it should be ensured that it is really Pi (by calculation).

Comment: Ah, well, no. I don't think you can do it very cleanly (or at all, for that matter). You should [edit] your question to make that clearer.

Comment: if i am getting you right you want to solve equations in digital form, I mean with putting 3.14...(Math.PI) instead of (p) in equations ...i am not sure JS is what you need for this

Comment: I think there are different approaches to this problem, that's why I left it open to the community. Maybe the rounding in the end as I tried to described with `value/Math.PI` rounded to the 10th digit is 0. Or maybe a symbolic calculation. Or ...

Comment: What kind of calculations do you need to do? Could you give an example. I don't get what you are trying to do in the last paragraph.

Comment: Currently I am doing calculations for [circle formulas](http://www.echteinfach.tv/formeln/geometrie/kreis/). All inputs and results are rounded to 3 digits. I thought it would be great to let the user enter "pi" and the calculation is done with `Math.PI` instead of 3,142.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding the question here so please correct me if I am, but based on the link in the comments, you have:

> Umfang: 9,425 u = 2·π·r
>
> Flächeninhalt: 7,069 AK = π·r2

You can't just "do the calculation with pi", but if you want to output π, go about it the other way: you *can* calculate *without* it, treating it as an unknown, and just append it to the result as a string:

> Umfang: 3π u = 2·π·r (result = (2 * r) + "π")
>
> Flächeninhalt: 2.25π AK = π·r2 (result = (r * r) + "π")

Comment: Nice and easy idea, so removing it, doing the calculation and adding it later on as a string. For this case, I just need to add an extra line for each result, showing the "pi-calculation". This way, pi would survive!